# How to mark function argument to be an instance of any class, inheriting classes i set

Tags: python, python-3.7, typing

I want to mark an argument of a function as instance of any class, inheriting classes i set.

`Union` is quite similar, but it works like `OR`, so

```py
a: Union[A, B] # means a is an instance of A `OR` B or any inherited classes
```

I'd like to do the opposite:

```py
b: Intersection[A, B] # a is an instance of any class inherited from A `AND` B
```

```py
class A:
    def a(self): return 0

class B:
    def b(self): return 0

class C(A, B): pass

class D(C):
    def b(self): return 1

class E(A, B):
    def e(self): return 0


def foo(a_and_b: Intersection[A, B]):
    pass

# i expect static analyzer to show:
foo(42) # not OK
foo(A()) # not OK
foo(B()) # not OK
foo(C()) # OK
foo(D()) # OK
foo(E()) # OK
```

Answer (score 0):

use `CLASS_NAME.__mro__` to get a tuple of all the parent class(including itself) of that class and use `type(instance_name)` to get the class of an instance. from this you can create a set data structure and find what you want.

```
>>> class A:
    pass

>>> class B:
    pass

>>> class C(A,B):
    pass

>>> c = C()
>>> type(c).__mro__
(<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to highlight function misuse by static analyzer. Most similar cases are covered by typing